# Workflow using vim together with midnight commander

Tags: vim, mc

As a huge fan of terminal applications, I use mc and vim on a daily basis. However, I never figured out a practical way to efficiently use both together.

In a gui application I would browse through my data and then open multiple files with a word processor.

When I use F4 in mc to open a file in vim, I cannot browse anymore or open other files. In an ideal world, I should be able to open vim from mc, keep on browsing and open additional files as tabs in the same vim session.

Does anyone have a better workflow?

Comment: You should setup your `EDITOR` to a command which opens a new tab and then runs Vim in it. How exactly it's done depends on your terminal emulator. To share a single Vim session you can try `vim --remote` parameter (only available if it `has("clientserver")` build option).

Comment: Try `:Explore` in vim